# URL refusing to match for me

Tags: python, django

Currently learning the ways of the Django. But stuck on the following.

html

```
<a href="{% url 'module:review' module.name area vocabs.name 'Review' %}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-block" role="button">Review</a>
```

url.py

```
url(r'^(?P<module_name>\w+)/(?P<area>\w+)/(?P<vocab_name>\w+)/Review$', views.review, name='review'),
```

views.py

```
def review(request,module_name,area,vocab_name):
try:
    vocabObj = Vocab.objects.get(name=vocab_name)
    if area == 'Vocab':
        reviewItems = vocabObj.vocabcontent_set.all()
    elif area == 'Phrase':
        reviewItems = vocabObj.phrasecontent_set.all()

except Modules.DoesNotExist:
    raise Http404("No Words found")
return render(request, 'module/reading.html', {'reviewItems': reviewItems})
```

The error i'm getting

```
NoReverseMatch at /Introduction/Vocab/
Reverse for 'review' with arguments '('Introduction', 'Vocab', 'Numbers', 'Review')' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

Comment: Is this your top level `urls.py`? Also what is the exact URL you are trying to access? You don't seem to have a url route matching `/Introduction/Vocab/`. Are you sure you read https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/urls/?

Comment: Your URL contains three parameters, not four, you should here *drop* the `'Review'` in the `{% url ... %}`.

Comment: rest of the url.py

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.home, name='home'),
    url(r'^(?P<module_name>\w+)/$', views.sections, name='sections'),
    url(r'^(?P<module_name>\w+)/Vocab/$', views.vocab, name='vocab'),
    url(r'^(?P<module_name>\w+)/Phrase/$', views.phrase, name='phrase')

Comment: I'm trying to get to

/Introduction/Vocab/Numbers/Review

Comment: as @WillemVanOnsem said. The 'Review' argument is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

For the given URL

```
url(r'^(?P<module_name>\w+)/(?P<area>\w+)/(?P<vocab_name>\w+)/Review$', views.review, name='review')
```

You clearly have three variable path parameters, `module_name`, `area` and `vocab_name`. The last one is not a variable path parameter and hence should not be included in the URL reverse

```
{% url 'module:review' module.name area vocabs.name 'Review' %}
```

The correct way would be

```
{% url 'module:review' module.name area vocabs.name %}
```

For extra reading, you can check out this part of the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/urls/#reverse-resolution-of-urls).